# The 100 dollar bill puzzle

Tags: cipher, pattern

[image]

Hi, my friend gave me a puzzle, and I need help in solving it. 
I am required to decrypt this code and get a password. 
Please help! The hint is: **$100 bill**.

---

Here's the text version of the image above:

```
A,M,L, ,F,M,A,A
N,L, ,C,F,H,E,G
L,U, ,E, ,E,T,
H,W,I,I,S, ,L,T
F,N,O,T,H,E,C,E
 ,N,R,O,M,O, ,E
 , ,E,A, ,N,T,T
M,T, ,R,E,T,T,E
```

Comment: Can we assume USD $100? Does it matter which version of the bill we reference? Does it matter that some of the letters are indented with spaces or is that in error?

Comment: Are you sure that spacing is correct? Some of them look off.

Comment: I have a hunch regardless...

Comment: @JoeZ. I did my best to match the image but, given that it's an image, I can't be positive. I'd like OP to weigh in if the spacing even matters.

Answer (score 30):

So it was reading Dan Brown's *The Lost Symbol* that got me the answer to this one, along with that one deleted answer that mentioned "Benjamin Franklin" (because his face appears on the US $100 bill).

The key is to use the "order eight Franklin square" mentioned in that book, and map each letter of the grid to that position. Specifically, this one (from [this site](http://www.pleacher.com/mp/puzzles/mathpuz/maghist.html)):

[image: Benjamin Franklin's magic square.]

If we do that, we get:

> TELL WON THE NAME GF THE ELEMENT TTHAT COMES AFTER CALIFORNIUM

Which I assume was *supposed* to read:

> TELL NOW THE NAME OF THE ELEMENT THAT COMES AFTER CALIFORNIUM

Which is, of course, [einsteinium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einsteinium).

Comment: @Beef: If my answer is correct, click the green tick mark to accept it.

Comment: IHHDWNLR GESAA  TP EOO TTIII R ROC SKGOEAW NTUNIORRASSRNGASPSIPE

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That message starts with "SAGHEIS" and is only 63 letters long, so I assume you missed a space somewhere.

Comment: @JoeZ. Oh sorry. Two spaces after GESAA :-)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage `_TSK_PTSNIHY_LOGN___A_UPYIDOLRFBWNSHIOEEW_A_H__TREHONPUEWTNEVC_I` ;-)

Comment: @JoeZ. `_IAAAAN_DGNSDAFDAVVEN_GDRE_NNEN_DA__BWLAPUD__SORNC_I_T_ENIIOMREG` :-(

Comment: @squeamishossifrage `.SOD LEOPPE TDIM` :P

Comment: We demand closure!!!

Comment: @Daedric I don't get it.

Comment: @Beef Joe and Daedric would like you to accept this answer :P